# sparkR, how to use sql() function?

Tags: sql, r, apache-spark, sparkr

I recently start using SparkR. I am using Rstudio server.
but when I run

```
sql_tmp3 <- sql(sqlContext, "FOR i IN 1..3 LOOP
            INSERT INTO tmptable VALUES (i)
            END LOOP")
```

I get the error:

[image]

what is the problem?
help me please

Answer (score 0):

Problem is you're using two unsupported constructs:

- `FOR` loop - loops are not supported at all
- `INSERT INTO ... VALUES ...` - the only `INSERT` form which is supported is

  ```
  INSERT INTO ...
  SELECT ... FROM ...
  ```

Answer (score 0):

**Spark Sql does not support Advance SQL. You can not use For...Loop & INSERT in spark SQL.**
Using For loop in Spark is not good practice. If you want then you can use foreach instead of this.

Roughly you can use your code in below way:
  Create dataframe of Seq from 1 to 3 with name sql_tmp2 and write with overwrite over tmp (tmptable), if you have only one column in tmp dataframe.